# Reference rewriten address with Request.Url

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I am using a custom asp.net rewriting module for some time now, and I would like to know how to reference/get a rewritten address (the url that shows in address bar) of an original url using Request.Url?

When I reference url with Request.Url.AbsoluteUri I always get the original address and not the rewritten one. One solution is to encode the original url once again, but I was looking for a different solution where I could actually reference this new url.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for Request.RawUrl.